# Failed to start neutron-server.service: Unit neutron-server.service not found

Tags: networking, server, services, openstack

I try to start neutron-server as a service  I get the following error:

$ service neutron-server start
$ Failed to start neutron-server.service: Unit neutron-server.service not found.

Comment: Sounds like neutron-server isn't installed as a SystemD unit, or has a different name.  How did you install neutron server?  (Try typing `systemctl start neutron` then hit the "tab" key to try and complete it - what shows up as options, if anything?)

Comment: how can i verify  and send me steps install neutron server please , thx

Comment: Nothing shows up as option !!